# Общие значения из двух запросов

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица

```
item_id, division_id
1        1
1        2
2        1
3        1
4        1
```

Как выбрать item_id, которые идут и к division_id= 1 и к division_id= 2?
Т.Е. должны быть уникальные item_id, которые относятся только к 2 или более разделам?

Comment: Приведите пример результирующей выборки

Comment: Select * from table where division_id = 1
Получаем 1,2,3,4
Select * from table where division_id = 2
Получаем 1

Окончательный ответ должен быть 1 - есть и там и там

Comment: таких вопросов сотни. только чуть чуть отличаются. вот никак не решу с каким по дублю закрывать ... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=%5bmysql%5d%20having%20count

Comment: Закройте вопрос, я его перепишу иначе!

Comment: Перепиши этот, зачем плодить вопросы?

Comment: @Gleb Под вопросом есть ссылка 'править'. воспользуйтесь ей что бы отредактировать вопрос, если есть какое то хитрое требование из за которого не подходят ответы на похожие вопросы. Правильно сформулированный вопрос - половина решения

Answer (score 0):

С помощью [DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) можно выбрать уникальные значения:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`item_id`) FROM `table` WHERE `division_id` IN(1,2)
```

Comment: Он выдаст и товары группы 1 и товары группы 2, а нужно товары, принадлежащие и группе 1 и группе 2 одновременно!

Answer (score 0):

Группируем по `item_id`, считаем во сколько `division_id` входит каждый, берём только те, что входят в 2 и более.

```
SELECT item_id
FROM `table`
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING COUNT(division_id) > 1
```

Для выборки по конкретным `division_id` можно добавить

```
WHERE division_id IN (1, 2)
```

---

Метод грубой силы:

```
SELECT item_id FROM `table` t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `table` a where a.item_id=t.item_id AND a.division_id IN (1,2,3,4,5))
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `table` a where a.item_id=t.item_id AND a.division_id = 6)
```

Comment: Выдает правильно. А если division_id не 2, а больше? В идеале, должно быть division_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND division_id = 6, т. е. Стандартно идет выборка IN (...), а потом, иногда нужно добавить второй раздел(только один)

Comment: Почему этого не было в вопросе?

Comment: @Gleb, Последняя редакция ответа точно не подойдёт? =)

Comment: Вот примерно то, что нужно, но почему то выдает все-все записи таблицы

Comment: Получается так: SELECT item_id FROM table 
WHERE division_id IN (1) AND item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM table WHERE division_id = 2)